# No rows present in the request when stream importing into Big Query

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery, google-api-ruby-client

I was trying to stream import data into big query using `tabledata.insert_all`

```
job_data = {
  kind: 'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest',
  rows: [
    { json: { column_name: value} }
  ]
}

response = execute(
  api_method: bigquery.tabledata.insert_all,
  parameters: {
    projectId: config['project_id'],
    datasetId: DATASET_ID,
    tableId: table_id
  },
  body_object: job_data
)
```

But I always get the following error message

```
Google::APIClient::Request Sending API request post https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/propane-tribute-90023/datasets/development/tables/api_requests_20150414/insertAll {"User-Agent"=>"My Test App/1.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.5 Mac OS X/10.9.5\n (gzip)", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ya29.VgFYvU2nxGDhWiCdS47XRw0J-7GLenRry0Cd3AA2D1RDzMh5gnf-m85I5GeSr9oNW51OuUb9mdwObg", "Cache-Control"=>"no-store"}

Decompressing gzip encoded response (155 bytes)
Decompressed (261 bytes)
Google::APIClient::Request Result: 400 {"Vary"=>"X-Origin", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "Date"=>"Wed, 15 Apr 2015 03:14:17 GMT", "Expires"=>"Wed, 15 Apr 2015 03:14:17 GMT", "Cache-Control"=>"private, max-age=0", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "Server"=>"GSE", "Alternate-Protocol"=>"443:quic,p=0.5", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked"} => {"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"No rows present in the request.", "locationType"=>"other", "location"=>"rows"}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"No rows present in the request."}}
```

Does anyone have the same the issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you pasted an example javascript snippet? Could you take another look at your question and make sure it makes sense?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, yes I am still stuch here, do you need any extra info?

Comment: @Nick, it is not a javascript snippet, I'm calling api using google-api-ruby-client. You can see from the error message. The api request went throught successfully, but alway return a response saying: "No rows present in the request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are providing appropriate values for all of the column headers present in your table’s schema. Providing separate “json” entries will populate individual rows with the column data you provide. Unless you have already assigned values to the variables named column_name and value, you need to provide those values in the statement following the json declaration.

A sample Ruby syntax for a tabledata.insert_all “rows” operation would look as follows:

```
body = {
   "rows" =>[ 
      {"json" => { "person_id" => 10, "person_name" => "test"}}, 
      {"json" => { "person_id" => 11, "person_name" => "test2"}} 
   ]
}
```